# Embeddings of finite boolean algebras

Tags: order-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

I have finite boolean algebras $B_1, B_2$ and an injective homomorphism $e : B_1 \hookrightarrow B_2$ between them. I'd like to know whether the following fact is true:
Does there exist for every $y \in B_2$ some $a, x \in B_1$ such that $a$ is an atom (i.e. $0<a$ and there is no $b \in B_1$ with $0<b<a$. Equivalently, if $B_1$ is a powerset algebra, then $a$ is a singleton set) and $e(x) \le y \le e(x \lor a)$?

I know that $\bigvee_{B_2} {\downarrow\! y} \cap e[B_1]$ and $\bigwedge_{B_2} {\uparrow\! y} \cap e[B_1]$ exist and lie in $e[B_1]$. And $y$ lies between them. But if $y \notin e[B_1]$ does an atom $a \in B_1$ exist s.t. $e(a) \lor \left( \bigvee_{B_2} {\downarrow\! y} \cap e[B_1] \right) = \bigwedge_{B_2} {\uparrow\! y} \cap e[B_1]$? Or is there a better candidate for $x$?

(Note: I write $e[B_1]:=\{ e(x) \mid x \in B_1 \}$ and ${\downarrow\! y} := \{ y' \in B_2 \mid y' \le y \}$ and ${\uparrow\! y}$ similarly with the other inequality.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every finite Boolean algebra is isomorphic to a power set and every homomorphism of finite Boolean algebras is induced by a map of the corresponding sets.  So your question is equivalently: given two finite sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ and a surjection $f:S_2\to S_1$, for each $y\subseteq S_2$ does there exist $x\subseteq S_1$ and $a\in S_1$ such that $f^{-1}(x)\subseteq y\subseteq f^{-1}(x\cup\{a\})$?  Now it should be easy to see the answer is no: for instance, if $y$ contains some but not all of the points of $f^{-1}(\{s\})$ and $f^{-1}(\{t\})$ for two different $s,t\in S_1$, then $x$ would need to exclude both $s$ and $t$ but $x\cup\{a\}$ would need to include both $s$ and $t$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was a bit overeager with accepting it, because I found a detail I don't get.

I see how every map $f : S_2 \to S_1$ induces a map $e : \mathcal{P}(S_1) \to \mathcal{P}(S_2); A \mapsto f^{-1}[A]$, which is a homomorphism of (complete) boolean algebras.
But I don't see how from $e$ I should construct $f$. Could you explain more?
I believe $f$ should be defined by $f(y) = x$ iff $y \in e({x})$, but I don't see how to show that this is a function i.e. well-defined.

Comment: $e$ must send the singletons in $\mathcal{P}(S_1)$ to some partition of $S_2$.  Then take $f$ to be the function whose fiber over each $x\in S_1$ is $e(\{x\})$.

Comment: Alternatively, this is just a special case of Stone duality, since the Stone space of $\mathcal{P}(S)$ is $S$ with the discrete topology if $S$ is finite.

Comment: Is it necessary that the $S$ are finite for $e$ to be of this form? Or would it fail with infinite powersets/boolean algebras?

Comment: Yes, it can fail for infinite sets.  For instance, a nonprincipal ultrafilter on an infinite set $S$ gives a homomorphism $\mathcal{P}(S)\to\mathcal{P}(\{*\})$ that is not induced by any function $\{*\}\to S$.